# XSLT:3.0 Employee Report output format has header & line record. Any way to achieve Total Emp counts on header record using for-each & accumulator?

Tags: xml, xslt-3.0

I want to get following output:
**Header Record** should show: Total number of employees in the report

### **Line Record** should show: Emp ID|First Name

Here is my XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
<xsl:output method="text" indent="no"/>

<xsl:accumulator name="emp.count" streamable="yes" as="xs:integer" initial-value="0">
<xsl:accumulator-rule match="Employee_ID/text()" select="$value +1"/>
</xsl:accumulator>

<xsl:mode streamable="yes" on-no-match="shallow-skip" use-accumulators="emp.count"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:for-each select="copy-of(Employee_Data)>
<xsl:value-of select="Employee_ID"/>
<xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="First_Name"/>
<xsl:value-of select="accumulator-after('emp.count')"
<xsl:text>&#xa;&#xd;</xsl:text>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: If you want to use XSLT 3 and streaming then, due to the forwards only processing of streaming, you can only output the total of some type of element after having processed them all. So a header record to output the total number of certain elements is not possible with a single pass and streaming, you only have that information after processing the elements, so you can put it into a footer. Or you need to process the same input twice. Unless of course you can use traditional, tree based XSLT where `count` and/or `accumulator`s can be used freely.

Comment: Hi Martin, Thanks for your response. I am trying to understand the two pass solution. For <xsl:param name="input-uri" as="xs:string">input1.xml</xsl:param> line code, do I have to pass the name of the xml document? I am getting the input from a web service so I wanted to know if and how I can rather pass an xpath to the param input-uri?

Comment: The used instruction `xsl:source-document` expects a URI (see https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#source-document-instruction) so the file name used in the sample of the answer is just an example of a simple relative URI. It can of course also an absolute URI e.g. `http://example.com/service/foo` that returns the XML. You would need to show more details as on how you use XSLT 3 and streaming (with Saxon EE?) like your Java or .NET code if you run the XSLT processor from your own code.

Answer (score 0):

The only single pass streaming processing that could output the employee data you want to output before the employee count would need to buffer the employee data, for instance in a sequence of maps:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    expand-text="yes"
    version="3.0">

    <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-skip" streamable="yes" use-accumulators="#all"/>

    <xsl:accumulator name="employees" as="map(xs:string, xs:string)*" initial-value="()" streamable="yes">
        <xsl:accumulator-rule 
            match="employee" 
            select="$value, map{}"/>
        <xsl:accumulator-rule 
            match="employee/id/text() | employee/first-name/text()"
            select="$value[position() lt last()], map:put($value[last()], local-name(..), string())"/>
    </xsl:accumulator>

    <xsl:output method="text"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
        <xsl:text>Employee count: {count(accumulator-after('employees'))}&#10;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="accumulator-after('employees') ! (?id || '|' || ?first-name)" separator="&#10;"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/93dFepX/1 has the code with a simple input sample but there Saxon HE is used so streaming is ignored but I have checked that the code works with streaming with Saxon 9.9 and 10 EE.

A two pass solution that processes the document once for counting and then the second time to stream out the details would be

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    expand-text="yes"
    version="3.0">

    <xsl:output method="text"/>

    <xsl:mode streamable="yes" on-no-match="shallow-skip"/>

    <xsl:param name="input-uri" as="xs:string">input1.xml</xsl:param>

    <xsl:template name="xsl:initial-template">
        <xsl:variable name="employee-count" as="xs:integer">
            <xsl:source-document href="{$input-uri}" streamable="yes">
                <xsl:sequence select="count(employees/employee)"/>
            </xsl:source-document>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:text>Employee count: {$employee-count}&#10;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:source-document href="{$input-uri}" streamable="yes">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:source-document>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="employee">
        <xsl:value-of select="copy-of()!(id, first-name)" separator="|"/>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>  

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Run it with `-it` as the command line option, passing the source file to be processed as the parameter `input-uri`.

Comment: A two-pass streamed solution is possible: output the "header" at the end as a separate document using `xsl:result-document`; then in a second streamed pass over the principal output document, stitch the header back in at the start. The second pass could be done using XInclude rather than XSLT if preferred.

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks for your response. I have used the for-each element due to which the accumulator repeats for every emp ID. Can you please refer to my code and share the changes you recommend?